# build.xml can not be found in openfire

Tags: eclipse, svn, openfire

I want to build openfire plugin in eclipse. I Create Openfire Project according to [Openfire SVN + Eclipse 3.3 + Subversive Installation Guide](https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1020)

After creating project I want to build openfire plugin but **build.xml** can not be found in the build directory inside the Openfire source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build OPenfire from source you  need Apache-Ant.
The build.xml is under OpenfireSRC/build.
You can use this tutorial
[Build Openfire from source](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html)